# WebApp authenticating in Authentication and Authorization - How to do?

Tags: authentication, primefaces, active-directory

I am looking for a way to make my web app using primefaces 5 to be able to authenticate and authorize the logged user to do or do not something.  I use Wildfly 8 and read that I can define a security domain like described here (https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LDAPSecurityRealmExamples).  This is the way I would like to do because - if I am not mistaken - I will have little codificaion extra in my app.

The problem that I must solve/understand is how my web app will supply the credentials of the logged user to the AD.  I will need to develop a class to intercept the login/pass from the form submit?
And how my App can use the EL defined here (http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=717) if my Roles are defined in a OU named Roles inside my AD?